# Canary traffic management from within Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I’m trying to achieve canary-style traffic management for applications which are not yet part of the Istio service-mesh but still are in the same k8s cluster. For example:

`Pod` A in the namespace `non-mesh` calls `Service` B in namespace `mesh` which is bound to the pods inside the service mesh. A desired state would be when traffic to these pods is distributed by the rules described in related `VirtualService` object.

Is this possible by Istio’s native facilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Istio a `VirtualService` Objects inserts a Route rule inside the service mesh sidecars. These routes rules are evaluated on the client-side (In your case that would be the sidecar associated with `Service A` if there was a sidecar present with it). Due to this, you can't perform traffic management between `Service A` to `Service B` ( As there is no client sidecar). One possible method to solve this, in case you don't want to enable mesh for the entire `non-mesh` namespace is to only insert sidecars for `Service A`. This will create all the necessary rules in the sidecar and then you can use traffic weights to modify requests between Service A and Service B

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm a little confused here. Isn't a `Gateway` object supposed to provide traffic management functionality to the inside-cluster communication as it does for the external clients? In other words: why specifying internal hostname like `service-b.mesh.svc.cluster.local` in the `Gateway` object and creating a matching `VirtualService` doesn't provide needed traffic management functionality?

Comment: A Gateway object works by creating the necessary routes in some ingress/egress pods ( you select the target by using the selectors in Gateway object. It works for external traffic because in this setup your edge sidecars act like client sidecars and evaluate the rules there). in your case, it would not work as you are calling service B directly If you want to use this method, you will need to create some internal ingress pods and configure it to listen to Service B request ( Gateway is used to create listeners on edge proxies).

Comment: After this you can hit the ingress endpoint and use Service B as host headers, this will route traffic to service B and enable all the traffic management features, but this will add another additional Hop. Although this will work I will not recommend using this setup, because this will involve another problem of managing DNS ( In-service A you need the domain service-b.mesh.svc.cluster.local to resolve to ingress service rather than the actual IP of service B, there might be a workaround to configure this, but this will make the whole situation complex)

Comment: Thank you for the useful comments! After some time I came up with idea that I might utilize Istio Ingress Gateway functionality for the "internal ingress" usecase. However, I might need to use some DNS setup in order to resolve DNS queries from non-mesh pods to the Ingress Gateway `Service`.